# How do I know when a CSS animation should be applied to the containing element vs applied directly to the element?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a full background image slideshow without JavaScript and after trying to follow a code example, I'm not sure when it's appropriate to apply the animation to the element's container or when to apply it directly to the element itself. As you can see in the code, when the `img` was to be animated, the animation was applied directly to the element, but with the `h3` element, the animation was applied to the container. I just want to know the best practices.

Here's the link to the example: https://codepen.io/leetech/pen/AJGLq

```
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>A little something something</h3></div></li>
  <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
  <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
</ul>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>CSS3 <span>Fullscreen Slideshow</span></h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

```
.slideshow,
.slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}
.slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.slideshow li div h3 {
  font-family: "helvetica neue", helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
```

Could you please advise me on the better approach?

Comment: This isn't a best practice situation. You apply animations to whatever element you need to in order successfully display the animation.

Comment: Ok. But why is the animation applied to .slideshow li div {} instead of .slideshow li div h3 where only the styling is applied? Also, is it possible that the animation be added to .slideshow instead of .slideshow li span {}?

Comment: Because that's what the markup is...who knows? As I said, this isn't a best practice scenario, it's whatever was done to make the animation work as the developer intended. Maybe the titles aren't all h3, maybe there's other markup inside of that div..if you added other content, then targeting the h3 wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is less a question about best practice and more about desired result. The animation should only be applied to the element intended to be animated. Add the animation to the container only when the intention that every child is included in the animation.

I imagine there are going to be layered animations in the case of your slideshow. There will be slide-level animations which could be applied at a container level with element-level animations on child elements with special treatments.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question and has already been addressed in the comments. This is should be a comment.